# Creating a user profile from an omniauth hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have this code that creates (or updates) a user from an omniauth hash parameter:

```
  def self.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
    uid = auth_hash['uid']
    provider = auth_hash['provider']

    user = find_or_create_by(uid: uid, provider: provider)

    user.name = auth_hash['info']['name'] || ''
    user.email = auth_hash['info']['email']
    user.nickname = auth_hash['info']['nickname']
    user.avatar = auth_hash['info']['image'] || ''

    user.access_token = auth_hash['credentials']['token']

    user.location = auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']['location'] || ''
    user.company = auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']['company'] || ''
    user.member_since = auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']['created_at'] || ''

    user if user.save
  end
```

It is working, but it looks unpleasant. What can be changed in this piece of code, making it easier to read and/or beautiful?

Comment: Welcome to CodeReiview! Your question is on topic, but state only the code purpose in the title.

Comment: what do you recommend?

Comment: Creating user profile from `omniauth` hash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "default to empty string" bit should probably be done in the model. I.e. in a `before_validation` callback or similar.

You can also use [`Hash#slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) to pluck out certain keys:

```
user = find_or_create_by(auth_hash.slice(%w(uid provider)))

user.assign_attributes(auth_hash['info'].slice(%w(name email nickname))
user.avatar = auth_hash['info']['image']

user.access_token = auth_hash['credentials']['token']

extra = auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']

user.assign_attributes(extra['raw_info'].slice(%w(location company)))
user.member_since = extra['raw_info']['created_at']
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite the keys (e.g. in a loop or using [`transform_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys)) before using `assign_attributes`:

```
translations = { # could be a constant somewhere
  'image' => 'avatar',
  'token' => 'access_token',
  'created_at' => 'member_since'
}

attributes = auth_hash['info'].slice(%w(name email nickname image))
attributes.merge!(auth_hash['extra']['raw_info'].slice(%w(location company created_at)))
attributes['token'] = auth_hash['credentials']['token']

attributes.transform_keys! { |key| translations[key] || key }

user.assign_attributes(attributes)
```

Comment: that is pretty awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps use
[`assign_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html)?
Or use another implementation / call `send` yourself.

Otherwise, if you provide access to the attributes of `user` via `[]`
the assignments could be done in a loop.

That said, you can at least remove the duplicated parts:

```
def self.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
  uid = auth_hash['uid']
  provider = auth_hash['provider']

  user = find_or_create_by(uid: uid, provider: provider)

  info = auth_hash['info']

  user.name = info['name'] || ''
  user.email = info['email']
  user.nickname = info['nickname']
  user.avatar = info['image'] || ''

  user.access_token = auth_hash['credentials']['token']

  extra = auth_hash['extra']['raw_info']

  user.location = raw_info['location'] || ''
  user.company = raw_info['company'] || ''
  user.member_since = raw_info['created_at'] || ''

  user if user.save
end
```